# BIT shifting HEx values telnet

Tags: python

I'm controlling a device that reports back the total lamp time in seconds. The data is little endian.

```
0xXX, 0xXX, 0x2A, 0x30
```

So I know that value is 10800 seconds.

I'm not sure if I just grab each byte and then re-order the bytes with variables or do I
actually need to shift them? But If I shift them isn't it possible I will be losing data?

Comment: What code do you currently use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `struct` module to extract numerical values from a stream of bytes. You can specify the endian-ness of the encoded values.